# Dynamic Programming In Case Of Non Integral Bound

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given as input n items, where item i has a positive real-valued weight wi and a
positive integral value vi. You are also given a positive real-valued capacity W. Note that the weights
need not be integral. Give a dynamic programming algorithm that returns the value of the subset of
items with maximum total value subject to the total weight of the subset being at most W. (You
do not have to construct the actual subset of items.) the running time of your algorithm, should be polynomial in the largest item value vmax = max vi and the number of items n.

Comment: Is this a homework? We are not here to do it for you. What parts of the problem do you have issues with?

Comment: This is not a homework. I would like to clarify this

Comment: How about this: it's impossible, because you can't represent all possible reals in finite space. Any theoretical implementation has to potential to spend all eternity on transcendental inputs, and any practical implementation will just fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this would be to compute the minimum total weight required to achieve at least total value T, for successive integer values of T, until it becomes obvious that future minimum weights will all be greater than W. Then look back to find the highest value associated with a weight <= W. I believe that the minimum weights required for each successive integer value of T can be constructed by dynamic programming using the work already done for lesser values of T.

Answer (score 4):

I think doing this is not possible. If you multiply all weights by some value smaller than one, you want the algorithm to run faster than before. But that's not possible, because the problem didn't actually change.

Comment: +1. formally: assume such an algorithm exists. Given a knapsack problem, you multiple each item by `1/max{weight}`, and run this algorithm. This gives you a polynomial solution to the knapsack problem, which doesn't exist assuming P!=NP.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for the 0-1 knapsack problem runs in O(nW) time where n is the number of objects and W is the max weight. This is not a polynomial solution in the input size. What the question here asks is an algorithm linear in n and v_max, again not polynomial in the input size. If we consider fixed point representation for all weights, the problem is essentially the 0-1 knapsack problem for integral weights as multiplying by a constant factor makes all the weights integral.